# How to synchronise processing from WSARecvFrom() when using CompletionRoutine with multiple sockets

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, winapi

From the MSDN Documentation:

> The transport providers allow an application to invoke send and receive operations from within the context of the socket I/O completion routine, and guarantee that, for a given socket, I/O completion routines will not be nested. This permits time-sensitive data transmissions to occur entirely within a preemptive context.

In our system we do have one thread calling WSARecvFrom() for multiple sockets. There is one CompletionRoutine for that thread handling all call backs from WSARecvFrom() opverlapped I/O.

Our tests showed that this Completion Routine is called like triggered from an Interrupt. Called for a socket while still processing the completeion Routine from an other socket.

How do we can prevent that this completion Routine gets not called while it is still processing Input from an other socket?

What Serialisation of data processing can we use ?

Note there are hundrets of sockets receiving and sending realtime data. Synchronisation with waiting for multiple objects is not applicable as there is a maximum of 64 defined by the Win32 API.

We can not use a Semaphore because when newly called the old ongoing processing is interreupted so a Semaphore would no be realeased and new processing blocks for ever.

Critical Sections or Mutex is not an Option because the Completion Routine Call back is made from within the same thread so CS or mutex would accept anyway and would not wait till the old processing is finished.

Does anyone have an Idea or even better approach to serialze (synchronize) data processing ?

Comment: I think that the section of MSDN you quote is stating that if you perform some I/O from within your completion routine, then the routine will exit before that I/O causes another call into it. How are you setting up your receives? Can you provide some code?

Comment: As Remy pointed out, the only way this can happen is that your completion routine is blocking, more specifically performing an alertable wait.  If you're not sure how this is happening, put in code to detect the recursion and set a breakpoint; you can then examine the call stack and see where your completion routine is being interrupted.

Comment: Inside the Completion Routine we do use a Critical Section for the synchronisation of data processing. Based on your comment this must be the point where the thread goes into alertable wait state so the the completion Routine can be called again by the OS.Now to Keep this

Comment: So that means we should have an other Synchronisation mechanism that puts the thread NOT in an alertable wait state while waiting for an other operation to complete. I would like to keep working with Completion Routines because it seems to be a real effizient and fast way using less System resources. Now looking for an Idee for Syncronisation inside the processing of the Completion Routine. Maybe any Idee for a Wait Function putting the thread NOT in altertable state ?

Comment: I'm now thinking about polling inside the Completion Routine with a function like InterlockedCompareExchange() to sync execution of different threads. I'm not shure if a function like InterlockedCompareExchange() puts the current thread in an alertable state ? If the thread would go in an alertable state we would have the same problem as now when using crtital sections inside Completion Routine.

Comment: EnterCriticalSection() is not documented as entering an alertable wait state.  I'd be surprised if that were the case.  I strongly recommend you use a debugger to find out for certain which call(s) are causing the recursion.  While InterlockedCompareExchange() definitely won't cause any wait, I wouldn't recommend a busy loop; very inefficient, and would deadlock on a single-CPU system.

Comment: If and only if you can confirm that EnterCriticalSection() is causing the recursion (which I think very unlikely) try using WaitForSingleObjectEx() on a mutex with `bAlertable` set to `FALSE`.  This is much less efficient than using a critical section, but it guarantees that you won't enter an alertable wait.  **Another thought:** perhaps you're doing synchronous I/O, e.g., writing to the console or to a log file?  I'm not sure whether synchronous I/O causes an alertable wait state, but I wouldn't be surprised if it did.

Comment: I've done some testing, and on my system EnterCriticalSection() does not cause the system to enter an alertable wait.  (Neither does printf, so your problem might be something else entirely.)

Comment: Using Debugger really showed that WSASendTo() and also sendto() called from inside the Completion Routine can cause the thread to reenter the Completion Routine. WSASendTo() was used in synchronous I/O mode. At this point I'm not shure if it makes sence to go on with Completion Routines.

Comment: Did start now testing with Completion Ports...

Answer (score 4):

If you read the [WSARecvFrom() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741686.aspx) again more carefully, it also says:

> **The completion routine follows the same rules as stipulated for Windows file I/O completion routines. The completion routine will not be invoked until the thread is in an alertable wait state** such as can occur when the function WSAWaitForMultipleEvents with the fAlertable parameter set to TRUE is invoked.

The [Alertable I/O documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363772.aspx) then states:

> When the thread enters an alertable state, the following events occur:
>
> 1. **The kernel checks the thread's APC queue. If the queue contains callback function pointers, the kernel removes the pointer from the queue and sends it to the thread.**
> 2. **The thread executes the callback function.**
> 3. **Steps 1 and 2 are repeated for each pointer remaining in the queue.**
> 4. When the queue is empty, the thread returns from the function that placed it in an alertable state.

So it should be practically impossible for a given thread to overlap multiple pending completion routines on top of each other, because the thread receives and processes the routines in a serialized manner.  The only way I could see that being different is if a completion routine is doing something to put the thread into a second alertable state while a previous alertable state is still in effect.  I'm not sure what Windows does in that situation, but you should avoid doing it anyway.

> Note there are hundrets of sockets receiving and sending realtime data. Synchronisation with waiting for multiple objects is not applicable as there is a maximum of 64 defined by the Win32 API

The [WaitForMultipleObjects() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) tells you how to work around that limitation:

> To wait on more than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, use one of the following methods:
>
> • Create a thread to wait on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, then wait on that thread plus the other handles. Use this technique to break the handles into groups of MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.
>
> • Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject to wait on each handle. A wait thread from the thread pool waits on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS registered objects and assigns a worker thread after the object is signaled or the time-out interval expires.

I wouldn't wait on the sockets anyway, that is not very efficient.  Using completion routines is fine as long as they are doing safe things.

Otherwise, I would suggest you stop using completion routines and switch to using an [I/O Completion Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) for the socket I/O instead.  Then you are in more control of when the completion results are reported to you, because you have to call [GetQueuedCompletionStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986.aspx) yourself to get the results of each I/O operation.  You can have multiple sockets associated with a single IOCP, and then have a small pool of threads (typically one thread per CPU core works best) all calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` on that IOCP.  This way, you can process multiple I/O results in parallel, as they will be in different thread contexts and cannot overlap each other in the same thread.  This does mean, however, that you can perform an I/O operation in one thread and the result may show up in a different thread.  Just make sure your completion processing is thread-safe.

Comment: Another option is for the completion routines to do nothing but add the result of the operation to a queue, which can be processed when the alertable wait returns.  This should be just as efficient as I/O Completion Ports in the single-threaded scenario, and may be conceptually simpler.  If you need to use multiple cores, though, I/O Completion Ports are significantly more efficient.

Comment: @Remy But how one would set a timeout value for a UDP socket in a client IOCP? for example, if the server never responds back to your send, GetQueuedCompletionStatus() would block forever.

Comment: @amaninlove UDP does not guarantee delivery. Whether you use (non-)blocking sockets, Overlapped I/O, IOCP, etc, you have to handle the possibility that a response may not arrive. `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` does have a timeout parameter. However, it would usually be better to instead start a timer after the send, cancel the timer if the response arrives, and if the timer elapses then cancel the read operation with `CancelIo/Ex()` and let `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` report the cancelation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me thanks for all the helpful hints and comments to my question.

We did stop now using completion routines. We changed the application to use completion ports.

The biggest problem we had with completion routines is that every time the thread goes into an alertable state the completion routines can (and will) be called again from the OS. As seen in the Debugger also calling WSASendTo() from inside the completion routine puts the thread into an alertable state. So the completion routine is executed again before the previous execution of the completion routine comes to its end.

This makes it *nearly* impossible to synchronize data processing from multiple different sockets.

The approach using Completion Ports seems to be the perfect one. You then have control about what are doing when you are released from GetQueuedCompletionStatus() for processing a data buffer. You have to and you can do the synchronization of data processing by yourself in a linear fashion without being interrupted and newly executed while trying to process the data.

Comment: Note that WSASendTo only entered a wait state because you were using synchronous I/O.  You shouldn't be mixing synchronous and asynchronous I/O.  Using completion ports (while probably a good idea on general principles) is only masking the problem; if your synchronous I/O operation is delayed for any reason, all the rest of your I/O will stop dead until it completes.  That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yes we do use synchronous I/O when calling WSASendTo(). We do send lot of small RTAV Packets. Normally I would not expect that WSASendTo() should block for a longer time. Otherwise we would be in great Trouble anyway.But let me

Comment: But let me know: Could we use the same Completion Port with GetQueuedCompletionStatus() getting the Status of an a async WSASendTo() operation ? If yes how to distinguish between a completion of WSARecvFrom() or WSASendTo() ? Should we analyze the OVERLAPPED Param of GetQueuedCompletionStatus() and map it against the buffer(s) of our application? As far as I see the CompletionKey can not be used because of it is set only once for a socket when assigning it to the CP with CreateIoCompletionPort().

Comment: Yes, you can use the same completion port.  If there is only ever one operation pending on a given socket at a time then you can track which operation it was using the completion key (which presumably already points to a data structure).  If there are multiple simultaneous pending operations, then usually you would embed OVERLAPPED as the first element in a larger structure, and put your context information there.